# Jquery function calls more than one time

Tags: asp.net, jquery, blur

I am having an aspx page in which I am calling a user control. The user control I am using a pop up to display it when a user clicks a asp:linkbutton. In that user control I am having a textbox and I am calling a Jquery Blur to do some validation. While doing so the function is calling [blur] is calling twice. I just called an alert() with the textbox value.So I can see the alert is coming twice .What I need to do to avoid the second time. I need to do it only whenever  the user going out of the textbox and that also one time.

```
  $('#<%=txtCategory.ClientID %>').blur(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
```

This is called twice.Thanks for ur response.

Comment: your current code would be helpful.  this doesn't sound like something with a generic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$("input:text[id$='txtCategory']").blur(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using live event handler by any chance. if that is the case change it to bind blur.

Also if obj is the jquery object that you are trying to beind the blur event on you can add this code

```
if (obj .data("events") === null || obj .data("events") === undefined || obj 
.data("events").click === undefined)
{
function(){bind blur);
}
```